# Using getElementsByClassName to return multiple items

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS and I am following the W3CSchools Filter List guide which works great when using getElementbyId but as I understand, IDs must be unique to the page.

I have changed to getElementsByClassName but it doesn't seem to be working. I only want to filter results in the myUL class and not otherUL class which can be found in somedivclass3.

I would also like to be able to match whole or partial words in any order e.g.
"diff" would match 3 of the 4 li and "different even" should match 1 li.

JS:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementsByClassName("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names..">
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Go">

    <div class="somedivclass1">
       <ul class="myUL">
          <li>Text here</li>
          <li>Different text here</li>
       </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="somedivclass2">
        <ul class="myUL">
           <li>Even more different text here</li>
           <li>Wildly different text here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

   <div class="somedivclass3">
        <ul class="otherUL">
           <li>Footer link 1</li>
           <li>Footer link 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I'd like it to work as per the example on W3C Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

Thank you for all help!

Comment: You have zero elements with a class name of `myInput`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, I updated the code. I incorrectly updated the wrong part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote a bit your function, you can find it as a snippet.

First loop on the 'ul' with the right class, then second loop on the 'li'
With jquery you would do that on just one line :)

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  //var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  var uls = document.getElementsByClassName("myUL");
  for (var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++) {
    var ul = uls[i];
    var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (var j = 0; j < lis.length; j++) {
      var li = lis[j];
      var txtValue = li.textContent || li.innerText;
      if (filtering(txtValue, filter)) {
        li.style.display = "";
      } else {
        li.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

function filtering(text, searchString) {
    const regexStr = '(?=.*' + searchString.split(/\,|\s/).join(')(?=.*') + ')';
    const searchRegEx = new RegExp(regexStr, 'gi');
    return text.match(searchRegEx) !== null;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<div class="somedivclass">
  <ul class="myUL">
    <li>Text here</li>
    <li>Different text here</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="somedivclass2">
  <ul class="myUL">
    <li>Even more different text here</li>
    <li>Widly different text here</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @JulienRevaultd'A... This works but there are other <li> tags on the page and it filters those out as well which is why I wanted to restrict it to a single class. It also doesn't allow you to change the order of the words in the search for example "different" and "even" doesn't return any results.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your post, because I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: @JulienRevaultd'A...I have updated the question itself with further details. Thank you for your help thus far!

Comment: @JulienRevaultd'A... Thanks Julien. It definitely works better than before! The only issue is that I still need to restrict it to "myUL" as it's removing breadcrumbs and hyperlinks as well. I updated the code earlier with an extra div and another UL class. Could you please help?

Comment: @nr85 : Check last version, 1st loop on ul then loop on li.. you should have a look at jquery too, could help to simplify code.

Comment: @JulienRevaultd'A...This worked as expected. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JulienRevaultd'A...I've just figured that there's no button to reset the results and display them all again. I'm using an input type = submit and onclick instead. Do you know of a way of doing this please?

Comment: You could add a function that : gets all "myUL" <ul> element, then gets all <li> (you'll find that in the code I wrote) and then just loop over and li.style.display = ""

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` will return an array of elements because there can be a lot of elements with the same class. So instead try first looping through all the ul's and then in li's:

```
    for (i = 0; i < ul.length; i++) 
    {
      li = ul[i].getElementsByTagName('li');

      for(j = 0; j< li.length; j++)  
      {
        a = li[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;

        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) 
        {
          li[j].style.display = "";
        } 
        else 
        {
          li[j].style.display = "none";
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. I'd like it to look across multiple divs which it isn't doing. I have tried your suggestion but it only looks in the first div.

Comment: @nr85 you should loop through all the elements returned by `document.getElementsByClassName("myUL")` and not just the first element.

Comment: @ErtanHasani I tried the code you provided but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @nr85 did you add `j` to `var` part at the beginning?

Comment: @ErtanHasani Yes I did. Here's what I've got:
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, j, txtValue;

Comment: @nr85 well check the logic inside for loop. Since I just copy pasted it the logic